# php oop why add properties to class

Tags: php, class, properties

i am trying to understand the concepts of oop in php.
my question: why properties (here: $result and $operation) are added in the class, but it works fine if i dont add them and var_dump this, so the objects property is set.
example:

```
  class Calculator {

   protected $result;
   protected $operation;

   public function setOperation ( $operation) {
    $this->operation = $operation;
   }

 }
```

and here without:

```
 class Calculator {

   public function setOperation ( $operation) {
    $this->operation = $operation;
   }

 }
```

why is this important, sometimes i see a class without properties declared on top?

Comment: If they don't exist, php will define them as `public` properties. If you define them, you can specify their visibility however you want. It is probably better to define them if they can be defined, but also keep in mind that php allows for overloading properties using a `__set` and `__get` magic method which allows you to do whatever you want with them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should read the fine manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so you can define visibility. Sometimes you have a class that holds a variable which you want to modify using methods of the same class only. If you do not explicity define variables inside a class, they are always public and can be modified in any scope.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php